# How do I implement google maps yelp.com style?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, unobtrusive-javascript

I have multiple locations (20+ per page) that need to be mapped on a single map. I would like to click on a link for the location that is *not* dynamically generated (for SEO purposes) that would open the info window for the respective marker on the map.

Behavior should mimic http://maptheburg.com/ - but this map has the sidebar links dynamically generated.

[Yelp.com](http://www.yelp.com/c/dallas/restaurants) is the only site I have seen so far that manages to implement the Google Maps API with unobtrusive JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what the yelp implementation is but if it's unobtrusive JavaScript mapping you're after then your only feasible option is to deliver a static image rather than an interactive map where JavaScript is unavailable.

A quick walk through of this technique can be found [here](http://www.svennerberg.com/2008/12/unobtrusive-google-maps/)

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Yelp.com has it's own JavaScript library which is interacting/using Google Map's JavaScript API for maps. You might want to start by peeking in there.

Might want to also check out [PdMarker](http://www.pixeldevelopment.com/pdmarker.asp) for advanced Google Maps markers.

If I remember right, Yelp took one of the open-source markers implementations and modified it for their own uses.